# For SEO purposes, what are the pros/cons of defining page titles client side vs server side?

Tags: javascript, seo

Programmatically, which is better for SEO purposes: defining web page titles client side (e.g., via Javascript that executes before the closing body tag) or server side (e.g., dynamically generating the title based on page content before sending the whole page to the client)?

Thanks!

Comment: I think more and more people are liking how simple it is to program in client-side JavaScript but SEO for sure does not work. I'm working on an open source project to enable this to work called withjs.com and I need to see interest in others developers wanting to do this as well with me so anyone interested? Contact me at my profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is entirely worthless to use JavaScript to define your page titles. Most web-crawlers do not download the javascript, and certainly don't run it. The source of the page is pretty much everything a web crawler sees.

**Client Side** -> Pros: You get to use JavaScript. Cons: Ruins your SEO

**Server Side** -> Pros: Actually read by search engines. Cons: You don't get to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

As a simple rule - if it's done client-side then it simply doesn't exist as far as SEO is concerned.

That said, there's ***really*** no need to be setting such things client-side via JavaScript unless you're substantially changing the page content dynamically and even then the change in title isn't guaranteed to work on all browsers, may negatively affect the end user experience, etc.